# Python Ternary Operator Can't assigned

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
age = 22
message = "Allowed" if age >= 18 else message = " not allowed"
print (message)
```

What's wrong with this python ternary? Every time I try to execute it says can't assign to conditional expression.

Comment: You mean `message = "Allowed" if age >= 18 else " not allowed"`. You should search for your error messages.

Comment: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need the second `message =`: `message = "Allowed" if age >= 18 else " not allowed"` will work.

Essentially, the Python ternary operator works like this:

`[result] = [thing if true] if [condition] else [thing if false]`

All that's necessary is a condition and the two separate options: you don't need to assign the `message` variable twice.